# How to make a two column page with left navigation?

Tags: html, css, css-float, navbar, nav

Attempting to put the Nav bar containing Home, Menu, etc on the left of the page, and the rest in the center, and the windingroad.jpg floated to the right of all the text. I am lost in how to split these into multiple columns and continue, any help would be appreciated.

~HTML~

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JavaJam Coffee House</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="javajam.css">
    <style>
   #nav {
        background-color:#999;
        width:100px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        font-weight: bold;
        float:left; }

   #nav a {text-decoration: none;
           padding-bottom: 15px;

a:link; { color: #996633;}

a:visited { color: #ccaa66;}

a:hover { color: #330000;
}

  #nav ul { list-style-type: none;}

    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>
        <img src="javalogo.gif" alt="JavaJam Coffee House" 
             width="619" height="117">
    </h1>
    <p>Follow the winding road to JavaJam...</p>


<div id="nav wrapper">
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Jobs</a></li>
</ul>

</div>

<main>
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="windingroad.jpg" alt="Winding Road" 
         width="333" height="156" class="floatright">

</div>

<ul>
    <li>Specialty Coffee and Tea</li>
    <li>Bagels, Muffins, and Organic Snacks</li>
    <li>Music and Poetry Readings</li>
    <li>Open Mic Night</li>
</ul>
</main>
<p>
    12312 Main Street<br>
    Mountain Home, CA 93923<br>
    1-888-555-5555
</p>
<footer>
  <p>Copyright &#169; 2014 Javajam Coffee House</p>
  <p><a href="@college.edu">
  a@college.edu</a>.</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this, but here is one way:

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #navigation {
            width: 200px;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            z-index: 1000;
            overflow-y: auto;
            background-color: gray;
        }
        #main {
            margin-left: 200px;
            padding: 5px;
        }
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
    <h1>
        <img src="javalogo.gif" alt="JavaJam Coffee House" width="619" height="117">
    </h1>
    <p>Follow the winding road to JavaJam...</p>
    <div>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Jobs</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="main">
    <div>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <img src="windingroad.jpg" alt="Winding Road" width="333" height="156" class="floatright">
        </div>

        <ul>
            <li>Specialty Coffee and Tea</li>
            <li>Bagels, Muffins, and Organic Snacks</li>
            <li>Music and Poetry Readings</li>
            <li>Open Mic Night</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <p>
        12312 Main Street<br>
        Mountain Home, CA 93923<br>
        1-888-555-5555
    </p>
    <footer>
        <p>Copyright &#169; 2014 Javajam Coffee House</p>
        <p><a href="@college.edu">a@college.edu</a>.</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Wrap your navigation into one container and your content into another container then apply css to separate split these two containers so it can be left and right.

Also, for your css id attribute it cannot contain more than one word, because this value is unique.